# Angular version (13)

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I have a problem when running
the command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@13.0.0
```

I need angular (cli) and angular to be in version 13 but when running the command, angular (cli) is in 13 and angular in 15 which gives me an error with project dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDJXU.png)

when I run npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGeBr.png)

Comment: Welcome! Note: it's really important to provide properly formatted text for code/data/errors/input/output, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the "xlsx" library. To install, run the below command

```
npm install --force
```